# Device list showing XLA_GPU and tensorflow not using GPU

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

I am trying to use GPU with tensorflow but model is using only CPU. Following codes I tried:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Input, Embedding, Conv1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Reshape, Concatenate, LSTM, concatenate, Bidirectional, MaxPool1D, GlobalAveragePooling1D
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, OrdinalEncoder, StandardScaler
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model



def model_tmp():
    init_nodes = 256
    mlp_nodes = 1024


    X_crs_mod1 = Input(shape=(5,), name='cross_section_data_layer')
    X_crs_mod2 = Dense(init_nodes, activation='relu')(X_crs_mod1) 



    wkly_dat_mod1 = Input(shape=(16, 52),
                          name='WKLY_Data_Layer')
    wkly_dat_mod2 = LSTM(init_nodes, name='MC_WKLY_lstm1', return_sequences=True)(wkly_dat_mod1)
    wkly_dat_mod2 = Dropout(.3)(wkly_dat_mod2)
    wkly_dat_mod3 = LSTM(init_nodes, name='MC_WKLY_lstm2', return_sequences=True)(wkly_dat_mod2)
    wkly_dat_mod3 = Dropout(.3)(wkly_dat_mod3)
    wkly_dat_mod4 = LSTM(init_nodes, name='MC_WKLY_lstm3', return_sequences=True)(wkly_dat_mod3)
    wkly_dat_mod4 = Flatten()(wkly_dat_mod4)




    merged_layers = concatenate([X_crs_mod2, wkly_dat_mod4]) 



    Final_out1 = Dense(mlp_nodes, activation='relu')(merged_layers)
    Final_out2 = Dense(mlp_nodes, activation='relu')(Final_out1)
    Final_out2 = Dropout(.3)(Final_out2)
    Final_out3 = Dense(mlp_nodes, activation='relu')(Final_out2)
    Final_out3 = Dropout(.3)(Final_out3)
    Final_out4 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(Final_out3)



    model = Model(inputs=[X_crs_mod1, wkly_dat_mod1],  outputs=Final_out4)
    return model

model_tmp().summary()
```

[image]

When I list devices I am getting CPU, XLA_CPU and XLA_GPU:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
def get_available_gpus():
    local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
    return [x.name for x in local_device_protos]
get_available_gpus()
```

[image]
Can anyone help how would I use XLA GPU?? How do I use GPU with tensorflow??

I tried to use GPU but getting XLA_GPU in device list. I need to be able to use GPU with tensorflow